# Pass async callback into class constructor, using TypeScript and Node/Passport

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, passport.js

I'm using the [`passport-http`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-http) authentication library, whose documentation uses callbacks - but I'm using TypeScript classes with async/await, so I'm unsure of the syntax.

The library wants a `verify` callback, which queries the  database - which is an async operation. I defined it as a separate async function (so it's easier to test):

```
public verify = async (username: string, password: string, done: (error: any, user?: any) => void): Promise<void> => {
  // read from database asynchronously...
  try {
    const user = await this.UserRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (!user)
      return done(null, false);
    if (user.Password !== password)
      return done(null, false);
    return done(null, user);
  }
  catch (e) {
    return done(e);
  }
}
```

I then provide it to the library:

```
//public async init(): Promise<void> {                       // also works
public init(): void {
  const strategy = new PassportBasicStrategy(this.verify);   // async callback!
  passport.use(strategy);
}
```

My problems:

- If I declare it as `init()` instead of `async init()` it works. I assume that's because `async` modifier is only needed if the function has an `await`?
- But I passed an async callback into that constructor, in a sync function!... is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` is syntactic sugar for regular function that returns a promise. If a function doesn't use `await`, it doesn't benefit from being `async`.

If API that accepts a callback doesn't use a promise it returns, this is potential problem. It's acceptable to use promises and hence `async`, as long as this concern is addressed. Since API won't handle rejections, they should be handled by a user:

```
verify = async (username: string, password: string, done: (error: any, user?: any) => void): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    // reads from the database asynchronously...
    done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
}
```

Not calling `done` callback will result in incorrect behaviour, even if returned promise is settled.

> But I passed an async callback into that constructor, in a sync function

`PassportBasicStrategy` accepts potentially asynchronous callbacks, that's why callbacks have `done` parameter. It doesn't matter whether a function is `async` or not, as long as returned promise doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... I used your advice to update the `verify` function... is it okay?

Comment: I guess it is. You don't need `return` with `done`. It likely does nothing bad but gives wrong impression that callback return value matters, while it doesn't. Use `else if` if `if` are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take advantage of the async/await API. In this case, because the API is callback based, you can do the following:

```
const veryfy: BasicVerifyFunction = (username, password, done) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({
                username: username,
                password: password
            });
            done(null, user ? user : false);
        } catch(err) {
            done(err);
        }
    })();
};

passport.use(new BasicStrategy(veryfy));
```

Note the async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
(async () => {
    // Use await here
})();
```

Node.js also includes a helper function named [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to transform callback APIs into Promise APIs but it is not usable in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! I never thought I'd see IIFEs again, since I haven't used jQuery in ages, yet here they are! :-) Never knew about promisify, thanks for that.